# Segmentation Fault When Accessing Class Member Variable

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segmentation fault every time I try and access the List<*Thread> member of the Thread class. I have looked at a lot of other posts and I just cannot figure this one out. I'm really sorry that this is a basic question. Here is the important parts of my code:

Thread.h:

```
class Thread {
 private:
   /*...*/
 public:
   /*...*/
   List<Thread*>* waitingList;         // Added waitingList for threads who will run after
};
```

Thread.cc:

```
Thread::Thread(char* threadName)
{   
    waitingList = NULL; //list of threads that are waiting (from Thread::join())
    /* ... */
}

void
Thread::Finish ()
{
    Thread *t;
    while(kernel->currentThread->waitingList->IsEmpty()){ //<----Gets The Segmentation Fault here
         t = this->waitingList->RemoveFront();
         kernel->scheduler->ReadyToRun(t);
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

Here is the List class that is used

List.h:

```
template <class T>
class List {
  public:
    List();                     // initialize the list
    virtual ~List();            // de-allocate the list

    virtual void Prepend(T item);// Put item at the beginning of the list
    virtual void Append(T item); // Put item at the end of the list

    T Front() { return first->item; }
                                // Return first item on list
                                // without removing it
    T RemoveFront();            // Take item off the front of the list
    void Remove(T item);        // Remove specific item from list

    bool IsInList(T item) const;// is the item in the list?

    unsigned int NumInList() { return numInList;};
                                // how many items in the list?
    bool IsEmpty() { return (numInList == 0); };
                                // is the list empty? 

    void Apply(void (*f)(T)) const;
                                // apply function to all elements in list

    virtual void SanityCheck() const;
                                // has this list been corrupted?
    void SelfTest(T *p, int numEntries);
                                // verify module is working

  protected:
    ListElement<T> *first;      // Head of the list, NULL if list is empty
    ListElement<T> *last;       // Last element of list
    int numInList;              // number of elements in list

    friend class ListIterator<T>;
};
```

Comment: `kernel->currentThread->waitingList->I` so what happens when `waitingList == NULL`?

Comment: And your proof that, at some point, `waitingList` is no longer NULL? From reviewing the isolated snippets of code, the problem here seems to be what's normally called "Pointless Use Of Pointers". Why is `waitingList` a pointer, requiring it to be initialized at some point? Why it can't be a plain `List<Thread *>`? And, to the point, why is it a `List<Thread *>` instead of a `List<Thread>`? Getting rid of pointless use of pointers very often goes a long way to fixing a bunch of these bugs.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Wow great thanks. I think I tend to overuse pointers. Not sure why I got it in my head that its safer to just make something a pointer when in doubt. I thinks it's because I'm afraid of making copies.

Comment: If you are affraid of making copies then you really need to look into (const) references and move constructors :) I write a lot of code and usually dynamic allocations only happen in some core library functions and then its by making use of std::make_unique or std::make_shared. Also learn about the standard library containers, eg. std::list more often then not you can just reuse one of those (they will be tested, wont have memory leaks and most of the time have more then good enough performance)